# Material DateRangePicker set up a default range

Tags: java, android, materialdatepicker

I want in my `DateRangePicker` was a default selected range. How can I get that?

**My code now:**

```
            CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
            constraintBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointForward.now());

            MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
            builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintBuilder.build());

            final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();

            imageDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `MaterialDatePicker.Builder.setSelection()` method. Below code for setting today as the start date and end date:

**In Java:**

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance()
MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
builder.setSelection(androidx.core.util.Pair(now.getTimeInMillis(), now.getTimeInMillis())
```

**In Kotlin**

```
 val now = Calendar.getInstance()
 val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
 builder.setSelection(androidx.core.util.Pair(now.timeInMillis, now.timeInMillis))
```